# Return nested struct inside struct in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Seems to be relatively simple question but I am not able to find a direct answer to it on the docs or online.

If in Solidity I please have a struct with a  structs mapping  I am trying to return it in a function I am reaching a dead-end, if I set it the return type as 'memory' I receive an error that because it is nested it must be declared as 'storage' type but 'storage' type can not be used to return data from functions :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Nested {

    struct Parent {
        string parentPropertyA;
        mapping(uint=>Child) childProperty;
    }

    struct Child {
       string childPropertyA;
    }

    mapping(uint=>Parent) parents;

    function getParent(uint parentId) public view returns (Parent memory) {
        Parent memory parent = parents[parentId];
        return parent;
    }
}   

TypeError: Types containing (nested) mappings can only be parameters or return variables of internal or library functions.
```

Is nested structures mapping return not support and I must flatten it in-order to return it?

I saw questions regarding nested arrays but wanted to validate & verify!

Comment: Please edit your question and share the code that results in this error.

Comment: @James Roeiter - hey mate, if you found my solution useful, it would be awesome if you could upvote. Any further clarification you need, please let me know.

Comment: @Issei - I please made some clarifcations and added a code sample.
Are you please familiar with how it may be solved ?

Answer (score 1):

A struct is an object. to return it as a value, you have to flatten it.

If somebody has a magical trick, I would very interested to know it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to understand what exactly you require without looking at your code, but I have tried my best to solve the problem. The function `valueFromStruct` returns the inner struct values.

```
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0 < 0.9.0;

contract test {
    
    struct Identity {
        uint age;
        string name;
    }
    
    struct NestedIdentity {
        Identity identity;
    }
    
    Identity identity = Identity(29, 'Issei Kumagai');
    
    NestedIdentity nested_identity = NestedIdentity(identity);
    
    function valueFromStruct() public view returns(uint age, string memory name) {
        return (nested_identity.identity.age, nested_identity.identity.name);
    }

}
```

You can see that the values in the `identity` struct is returned when you call the function below.

[image]

The `valueFromStruct` function can also be written like this:

```
function valueFromStruct() public view returns(Identity memory) {
    return nested_identity.identity;
}
```

Both solutions can further be enhanced if you use a mapping object so that you can look up nested structs based on `uint` or `address` - i.e., you can have a collection of nested structs kept in one hash-table.